# In c#, is there a way implement abstract classes so the base constructor is called automatically with the first parameters provided?

Tags: c#

I have an abstract base class called Unit. I potentially want tens or hundreds of implementations of Unit.
Here is Unit stripped down to show only the constructor:

```
public abstract class Unit {
   public Unit(string unitName, Unit parentUnit,Transform parentTransform,Vector3 position,Quaternion rotation){
      //Do stuff with the parameters
   }
}
```

Here is an implementation (Factory) with one extra parameter (factorySize):

```
public abstract class Factory : Unit{
   public Factory(string unitName, Unit parentUnit,Transform parentTransform,Vector3 position,Quaternion rotation, float factorySize) : base(unitName,parentUnit,parentTransform,position,rotation){
      //Do stuff with factorySize
   }
}
```

But if I have hundreds of these kinds of implementations and if I want to change the base class parameter list, I have to go in and change that really long constructor line for each one so it matches the base class parameter list!

```
public SomeUnitType(string unitName, Unit parentUnit,Transform parentTransform,Vector3 position,Quaternion rotation, float factorySize) : base(unitName,parentUnit,parentTransform,position,rotation)
```

Is there a better way to do this so I don't need to manually tell the constructor to pass those first parameters to the base constructor?

Comment: you simply overload the abstract class with a different signature. But no there is no easier/lazier way to do it unless you want to use reflection which is another beast to worry about. 
Dependency Injection is used in modern application to instantiate objects.

Comment: First ask if you _absolutely need_ all of those parameters in the base constructor. In some cases you might simply need them in a specific method and can be passed as a parameter there instead. Otherwise, you can then try to reduce the parameter count by encapsulating groups of similar parameters into their own objects.

Comment: Resharper would speed up the refactoring process, if introduce a new parameter in the base class constructor via refactoring, it allows to refactor a call tree as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html#call_tree) in mouse clicks instead of copypasting the code

Comment: I am not sure of the actual structural problem you are trying to solve, yet "*I potentially want tens or hundreds of implementations*" seems very suspicious, and could likely be an X/Y problem.

Comment: devNull, I like the idea of reducing the parameter list and just making separate methods to modify them. Michael Randall, I like your point and I will think more on it but I think I'm going the right way because I need many objects of different behaviors/data but with a lot of common "Unit" behavior/data as well.

Comment: An type that has so many constructor parameters and so many inheriting types that managing the parameter lists for the constructors of the inherited types becomes a challenge, is a type that is almost certainly designed incorrectly. That said, one technique you can use to mitigate the work involves is to create a parameters type, such that the constructor takes only the reference to the parameters object. This avoids having to revisit all inheriting types any time a parameter is added/changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of Visual Studio 2019, you can generate the constructor automatically and then add the new parameters.

1. Right-click on the base class `Unit` and hit "Quick Actions and Refactorings...".
   [image: Step1]
2. Click "Generate constructor".
   [image: Step2]

From there, you can simply adjust the newly generated constructor with the parameters that you want.

Comment: This is an interesting tip. I'm using VS Code but there might be something similar. Thanks.